# browsing inside an iframe

Tags: url, iframe

I have a wordpress page that loads an 
iframe prompting the user to navigate through bing to a webpage he/she wants. After browsing and upon arriving at the page the user wants he/she has to press a button to copy the current ulr to the clipboard or to print the url through alert() or on screen.

Question: is there a status attribute or something else that can give me the current status / metadata of the iframe (i.e. what page the iframe is visiting at a specific moment?). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, it is forbidden to access any contents of an iframe that is not from your own domain, this is because of cross-site scripting restrictions.

You can read more about that here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

If you would be on the same domain however, you could do something like this in jQuery:

```
var url = document.frames['example-frame'].location.href;
```

when you would have an iframe like so:

```
<iframe name="example-frame" src="www.example.org"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you for your rapid answer. Any ideas how someone can achieve the above not with iframes but with something alternative? The url that the user would like to browse could be anything. Any page that someone can visit when someone opens a browser and surf the web.

Comment: Nope, it is quite impossible for a reason. If you were able to, you could get sensitive information of someone browsing within your website which is a security risk, hence the cross-site scripting restrictions are in place.

Comment: However, if on the embedded iframe I navigate to a different webpage (say www.a.com) and right click on it selecting "view frame source" (firefox 30.0) I get all the info I want. canonical urls, metadata about www.a.com (even if it is from a different domain). So I wonder if there is a way to load this frame source and extract from the xml file the current url. There has to be a way...

Comment: You really can't, javascript will not allow it, you can mark my answer till someone else makes a hack if you want.